# FP-injective , injective and pure R-module

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

prove that : FP-injective R-modules, which are pure-injective,
are injective ?
I know that an R-module M is called FP-injective if Ext1(N,M) = 0 for all
finitely presented R-modules N 
and R-submodule N of an R-module M is called pure in M if for all (finitely presented) R-modules F, the map : F⊗N → F⊗M induced by the inclusion map N → M is injective.
and an exact sequence 0 → N → M → L → 0 is called a pure-exact sequence if Im(N→M ) is pure in M.
 and R-module M is called pure-injective if it has the injectivity property
relative to all pure-exact sequences
but i cant got the proof ?

Answer (score 1):

FP injective module Is a module that the embedding in its injective envelope Is pure ; pure injective module  Is a module can be lift by pure extension . then we  consider the identity homomorphism  of M and it can be lift by the pure embedding to its envelope  and thus it Is a direct snmmand of  injective module and thus a injective module

Comment: Can you explain more, please